# How to build custom client for telegram?

Tags: telegram

I have an idea to extend telegram client, but not how to write it from scratch. My question is: Can I apply small changes to existing Telegram client (IOS version) and push it on AppStore as my own client, or do I have to build it all from scratch?

I've already downloaded and tried build Windows client, but it does not work.

Bot currently can't provide this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Telegram IOS Source From Github

> https://github.com/peter-iakovlev/Telegram

Clone From It, Open it from Xcode and edit that and build your version and do what you want!

Hope Thats help.

Comment: your wellcome, if this helped you please set this to Correct Response